# Python: Shorten concatenation by using inline conditionals

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, printing, concatenation

If the title is a bit obscure, an example of what I would like to do is:

`print("Status: " + if serverIsOnline: "Online" else: "Offline")`

I know this is improper, but what I am trying to do is check if `serverIsOnline` is `True` then print `Status: Online` else `Status: Offline`. I know it's possibe, I have seen it done, but I can't remember how it was done.

This is a shorter equivalent of:

```
if serverIsOnline:
    print("Status: Online")
else:
    print("Status: Offline")
```

Could someone please refresh me?

Comment: Tell me life-hater, what was wrong with my question as to deserve a downvote?

Comment: Wasn't me, but maybe it's because you could've easily found the answer by googling your question title?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Watch me as I edit this question to include a refute to that complaint.

Comment: you don't need to clarify with an edit on why you don't deserve a down-vote; don't clutter up the question with unnecessary content.

Comment: @spikespaz Hmm, I had literally copied+pasted your title verbatim into google and your question was the first result and the next three were results that answered your question. So you had tried that and didn't get such results? I wish I knew how Google does these things :-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann If you google "Shorten concatenation by using inline conditionals" the first result is indeed this thread. By the way, Google can't actually search for questions indicated by "How do I..." or "What is..." It will only compare the keywords with the site titles or meta tags of the sites it crawls. Try searching "How Google works" and it wouldn't look at the query as a question, it will look at it as a string to compare with the titles or search terms of sites it has stored in it's index. Sometimes, if its a frequent search, it will offer a small citation from another site.

Comment: @spikespaz Don't know why you're telling me about the first result being this thread but not telling me anything about the subsequent results. Also, you forgot the "Python: " part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [conditional expression](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) (*also known as a 'ternary' expression, usually with a* `?` *operator, used by many other languages*).

```
print("Status: " + "Online" if serverIsOnline else "Offline")
```

Syntax: `True if condition else False`

Comment: Answer accepted. A swift and simple execution, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Python allows inline `if/else` as long as an `else` is specified (`if` only is a SyntaxError). Most Python programmers refer to this as its ternary:

```
>>> server_online = True
>>> print('Status: ' + ('Online' if server_online else 'Offline'))
Status: Online
>>> server_online = False
>>> print('Status: ' + ('Online' if server_online else 'Offline'))
Status: Offline
>>> print('Status: ' + 'Online' if server_online)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print('Status: ' + 'Online' if server_online)
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```